# Why does the US have such a low score for "Political participation" factor in the Democracy index?

Tags: united-states, voting, democracy

According to [Wikipedia's article on Democracy Index,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index) the United States ranks 21st with the lowest indicators being *"Functioning of government"* and *"Political participation"*.

I am wondering why such a relatively low score in the context of universal suffrage (virtually anyone who is more than 18 years old can vote and registration may be accomplished when obtaining a driver's license).

**Question:** Why does the US have such a low score for the *"Political participation"* factor in the Democracy index?

Comment: As a side note, it seems that the aforementioned indicators changed US category from "Full democracy" to "Flawed democracy".

Comment: I am amazed that the US got 9.17 for pluralism with just 2 effective parties

Comment: While the answer from JamesK has the specific details of the ranking you're looking at, stories like this one in the Guardian probably contribute to some of those lower scores. https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/oct/19/midterms-how-the-votes-of-vulnerable-groups-are-being-suppressed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Economist has 60 indicators each of which is scored on a three point scale (0,0.5 or 1) the total is then calculated. For the participation section the following indicators are used:

> 27. Voter participation/turn-out for national elections.
> 28. Do ethnic, religious and other minorities have a reasonable degree of autonomy and voice in the
>       political process?
> 29. Women in parliament.
> 30. Extent of political participation. Membership of political parties and political non-governmental
>       organisations.
> 31. Citizens’ engagement with politics, from [World Values Survey](http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/wvs.jsp)
> 32. The preparedness of population to take part in lawful demonstrations, from World Values Survey
> 33. Adult literacy.
> 34. Extent to which adult population shows an interest in and follows politics in the news, from World Values Survey
> 35. The authorities make a serious effort to promote political participation.

(full details at [Democracy index 2017](http://pages.eiu.com/rs/753-RIQ-438/images/Democracy_Index_2017.pdf?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWkRKbU1HWmxNVEUwTW1FdyIsInQiOiJPdlltVFV0blFRQzZNVERCZHhVeitZRElmUGplOHh3NWs1d2wzVzdRS1JvNU1kVmUxQVRESU9LbEVSOVwvR1F4aG1PV1NlS0ZZcng4NzBcLzVNZ09JOUxiZU5TTEVPekVHayttOTRqQkQ5TkNzWGN08RlowQTZ0UzlUK0pDdm9PVGlcLyJ9)

The USA scores well for literacy and membership of political parties, but is still at 19% for women in the House, and doesn't score full points on indices such as percentage interest in news media and turn-out at elections.

Comment: Yes, that explains it. Ref. "percentage interest in news media" - does this mean that people are not that interested in reading politics related articles or something else?

Comment: You score 1 if in the World Values Survey, more than 50% of the population gets daily news. It may  be that more Americans use social media for news, and this has pushed down the %age who read a daily newspaper or watch the news every day

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is question 27 scored for states where voting is mandatory? On paper that would show very good turnout, even though it's a negative in terms of voting significance of concerned/informed citizens.

Comment: The answer is given in the linked document.  For Q 27  "If voting is obligatory, score 0. Score 0 if scores for questions 1 or 2 is 0." (Q 1 and 2 are "Are elections free" and "Are they fair")  So Australia, Belgium and other states with mandatory voting score 0 for Q 27)